# Joomla! Unset CSS in template index.php

Tags: php, css, joomla

I have a custom Joomla 3 template where I use

```
unset($this->_scripts[JURI::root(true).'/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js']);
```

to unset boootstrap functionality. It works fine for me. Now I want to use same technique to unset a css file and set another one for it.

```
unset($this->_scripts[JURI::root(true).'/media/system/css/calendar-jos.css']);
```

And it gives me no result.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: A stylesheet would not be in the `_scripts` array but probably one names `_styles` or `_stylesheets`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
unset($this->_scripts
```

to:

```
unset($this->_styleSheets
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but this did not have any affect. I put unset($doc->styleSheets[JURI::root(true).'/media/system/css/calendar-jos.css']); and also tried unset($doc->_styles[JURI::root(true).'/media/system/css/calendar-jos.css']); but css still is there

Comment: unset($this->_styleSheets[JURI::root(true).'/media/system/css/calendar-jos.css']);